# What does the trilinear coordinates of circumcenter mean?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles

I am reading a solution of determination of the circumcenter where I know the coordinates of any arbitrary triangle's corners. you can read it [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcenter.html)

I am just stuck in the first phrase and first formula ! since also there are lots of new variables introduced on the way of solution that are not depicted  on the schematic. could someone help me understand this solution ? I am somehow lost

Comment: Did you click on the [trilinear coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrilinearCoordinates.html) link?

Comment: @saulspatz no but now yes. the problem is in each line there is a new link and you should click into each page to know what is the next line ! I wish someone could have responded here